# How to remove zeros from datetime string C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I'm getting from API `DateTime.Date`, that means `Date` without time, and sometimes I'm getting `DateTime` with full valid date, but in case when I'm getting value without Time and since property is type of `DateTime` it will include also time but with value of zeros.

So my string looks like this:

```
29/08/2019 00:00:00
```

How could I recognize when it's without valid Time and remove this `00:00:00` from my string?

Thanks guys

Cheers

Comment: Take a look at [format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: @John Sometimes I'm getting full DateTime value, I need to recognize when it's with zeros and format it..

Comment: That's not what you asked in your question, although you could check `if (dt.Date == dt)` if you first parse it to a `DateTime` object (`dt`).

Comment: @Roxy'Pro You can use `if (dt.TimeOfDay.Ticks == 0) ...` to check whether dt represents midnight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it an then use `ToShortDateString` or `ToString("d")`:

```
string result = DateTime.Parse("29/08/2019 00:00:00").ToShortDateString();
```

> Sometimes I'm getting full DateTime value (with valid Time part), so I
>   need to recognize when it's with zeros and format it.. to short date
>   string, I can not use it in every case

Well, then compare the `DateTime` with it's own `Date` property:

```
string dateString = "29/08/2019 01:00:00"; // with this sample the 'if' will not be entered because there is a time portion
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
if(dt.Date == dt)
{
    // there is no time portion in this DateTime
    dateString = dt.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes I'm getting full DateTime value (with valid Time part), so I need to recognize when it's with zeros and format it.. to short date string, I can not use it in every case

Comment: You can use `if (dt.TimeOfDay.Ticks == 0) ...` to check whether `dt` represents midnight.

Comment: @TimSchmelter You are the man! Thx! Any recommended resources on c# learning?